# Apache mass virtual host dynamically

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have an Apache server that takes in all sort of domain that point to it, for example:

- test.com
- abc.com
- 123.com

Then, it will resolve these domain name to a sub folder, for example

- test.com -> /var/user/test
- abc.com -> /var/user/abc
- 123.com -> /var/user/123

I can do it using virtual host but i will need to manually add the entries and restart server each time there are changes.

Is there any way to do the setting dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section "Dynamic Virtual Hosts with mod_vhost_alias" in the [Dynamically Configured Mass Virtual Hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/mass.html) page of the Apache docs helped me out with this. The only part I had to add to my httpd.conf file was the following:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /www/hosts/%0/docs
VirtualScriptAlias  /www/hosts/%0/cgi-bin
```

The `%0` is the variable that takes whatever domain is being accessed and points it to the folder in `/www/hosts/` with the same name. `/docs` is the folder where you put your public HTML files for each site, a different one for each. You can edit those to what you want.

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 That's right! May be an example would have helped for his particular case.